Where did the woman at Stormhill Shack go?
There is a woman in Stormhill Shack who gave me a message to pass onto some "chrysalids" that have been grafted onto a spider in Stormveil Castle. I got the Chrysalid Memento from their corpse and returned to the shack, but the woman wasn't there anymore; there was just a Sacred Tear left behind, along with some flowers and a bottle (I think (only about the bottle, other stuff for sure)).
Apparently, she wasn't supposed to disappear, according to this NPC quest guide: 


Is it possible to find her again, and if so, where did she go?

This was Roderika, and if not in the shack, she is supposed to be in the Roundtable Hold:

Moves to Roundtable Hold after giving her the Chrysalids' Memento OR resting at any site of grace in the Liurnia of the Lakes region. The earliest possible trigger for acquiring Roderika's Golden Seed is resting at the Lake-Facing Cliffs grace.

